# Can't knit when running python codes in r markdown

Tags: python, r-markdown

When I put all my python codes in one chunk in rmd, I can successfully knit the file. However, when I put them in different chunks, it always shows the error:

```
  Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
    NameError: name 'variable name' is not defined
```

I search for the internet but still have no idea what's going on...